# How to call a console app recursively with arguments?

Tags: c#

I would like to have a console app that is passed in a arg to be able to call itself passing in the same command arg that was sent in initially.

If I try this however

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Assembly ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string cmd = Environment.CommandLine;

    Process again = new Process();
    again.StartInfo.FileName = ass.Location;
    again.StartInfo.Arguments = args[0];
    Console.WriteLine("Running with: " + args[0]);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    again.Start();
    return;
}
```

The initial call print "running with: Argument1" but the second call fails because the args array is empty.

Comment: Maybe the `Assembly` didn't like being called an ass, therefore refusing to identify itself. :)

Comment: There are some possible side-effects from the Project + Properties, Debug tab, "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" option.  Which makes your process yourapp.vshost.exe instead of yourapp.exe.  Skeet avoided it by not using the IDE.  Nothing obvious though, that can still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me. I compiled *exactly* this code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string cmd = Environment.CommandLine;

        Process again = new Process();
        again.StartInfo.FileName = ass.Location;
        again.StartInfo.Arguments = args[0];
        Console.WriteLine("Running with: " + args[0]);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        again.Start();
        return;
    }
}
```

Using the command line:

```
csc Test.cs
```

And then ran it as:

```
Test.exe hello
```

... and it started extra processes recursively, each of which printed "Running with: hello".

Comment: Confirmed :-). Modified a bit (1st argument), but kept the same logic. Runs ok here.

Comment: If I debug from within VS2008 and set the args under the Debug > Start Options > Command Line Arguments, it fails as described above, but if I run it from cmd.exe it works. Curious as to why. Thanks for the help.